# Command "python3 -m pip install [...]" failed with error code 1 in None

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to install the PyInstaller module for python through the terminal on my mac, and it is not working.

I am trying to install this module so I can package a program. I have tried to install through terminal through different commands (e.g. "pip install pyinstaller), but it is not working, even though I know I have PIP correctly installed.

When trying to install, I type, `python3 -m pip install pyinstaller`.

The result is `Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/w5/rlzrygt57j3c3nl4p29d2djc0000gw/T/pip-build-env-mjrd7sir https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/86/095d2f7829badc207c893dd4ac767e871f6cd547145df797ea26baea4e2e/setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=4380abcf2a4ffd1a5ba22d687c6d690dce83b2b51c70e9c6d09f7e8c7e8040dc https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=f4da1763d3becf2e2cd92a14a7c920f0f00eca30fdde9ea992c836685b9faf28" failed with error code 1 in None`

I have upgraded PIP, and tried using `sudo python3 -m pip install pyinstaller`, but I am not in the sudoers file.

Please help

Comment: Try the `--user` flag, probably won't work but doesn't hurt to try at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a virtual environment for your project in your project directory.

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Test which python is activated

```
which python
```

This will show that your local python in the virtualenv you just created is now the current python

Try installing now using

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

This ought to work for you. Always use virtual environments for your projects instead of installing system wide libraries unless you really need to set this up for the system.